# fullCalendar (v5) callback/handler anytime view is rendered?

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

What is the way to catch anytime a view is rendered?

Not only when switching views, but also when clicking today / prev / next?
I need to clear an array of unique event titles after (or before) each render is complete.

So, similar to `eventAllRender` which was [removed](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/upgrading-from-v3#event-rendering) starting v4.

Currently using `.click` event for all buttons, which does the trick, but I was hoping there was something really linked to the actual rendering.

```
calendar.render();

$('.fc-button').click( () => {
  console.log("do something")
})
```

Answer (score 9):

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet

> Called after the calendar’s date range has been initially set or
> changed in some way and the DOM has been updated.

```
datesSet: function(info) {
  // ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for this :) but be careful with datesSet, using Vue here and datesSet is called when calendar options (including events) changes and even if dates range has not change.